# grails war tomcat with external config file

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, war

I want to add external config data. So I added in the main `Config.groovy` file the following line.

I exported the environment variable

```
DASH_CONFIG=<path_to_external_configfile>/extConfig.properties
```

- extConfig.properties

  ```
  simpleBSMDash.default.serverName = "test.it.com"
  simpleBSMDash.default.refreshInterval = "5"
  ```
- Config.groovy

  ```
  if(System.getenv('DASH_CONFIG')) {
      println( "Including configuration file: " + System.getenv('DASH_CONFIG'));
      grails.config.locations = [ 
          "classpath:exthConfig.properties",
          "file:./extConfig.properties",
          "file:${System.getenv('DASH_CONFIG')}"]
  } else {
      println "No external configuration file defined."
  }
  ```
- Bootstrap.groovy

  I'm initialisation some config parameter in Boostrap.groovy.  for example

  ```
  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder


  new AdminSettings(
      refreshInterval:"${ConfigurationHolder.config.simpleBSMDash.default.refreshInterval}", serverName:"${ConfigurationHolder.config.simpleBSMDash.default.serverName}").save(failOnError:true)
  ```

When running locally the app through: `grails -Denv=DEV run-app`. Everything works fine, the intance AdminSettings is created and initialised with the expected values.

When I deployed the war file on my tomcat server, the intance AdminSettings is not intantiated. Yet I did export environment variable

```
DASH_CONFIG=<path_to_external_configfile>/extConfig.properties.
```

I event put the `extConfig.properties` file in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder, it did not work as well.

I rename it to `extConfig.groovy`, it did not help either.

I search through stackflow but did not find out a correct answer.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for us:

In conf/Config.groovy:

```
grails.config.locations = [ 
  "classpath:${appName}.properties", 
  "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties"
  ]
```

It works in Windows, though the places Groovy/Windows thinks is home (~) can be a bit surprising.  Your attempt to access an environment variable from Config.groovy looks a bit risky...

Comment: Or try this: http://phatness.com/2010/03/how-to-externalize-your-grails-configuration/

Comment: Thanks @CharlesW for you reply but I have already tested your option and it did not work...