# Setting external configuration file on linux

Tags: linux, grails

I'm trying to use external configuration to deploy a war.

This is my configuration for external file location in `config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = 
[
                "classpath:external-config.groovy"
]
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437929/grails-war-tomcat-with-external-config-file), but I still don't get it:

1. Where do I have to put file "external-config.groovy" on my linux server?
2. How can my server know "classpath" ?
3. Do I have to use an absolute path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235740/how-to-set-classpath-in-linux-to-let-grails-find-external-configuration does this help

Answer (score 1):

You can put this file in your tomcat lib directory. I generally put a println with some message as well in my external config to make sure it's loaded.